# Making own custom dynamic background (theme) for my android application?

Tags: android, background, android-theme

In my android application, there is a theme option . Where 4 images are available. After selecting one of image, I want to use that as a background in my entire application. But I am not sure how to do this and what is the procedure? I have tried something , but may be this procedure is not perfect. I stored the selected image inside sharedPreference inform of bytes and inside every activity, I set the image as background. But sometimes some activity's background is not changing and sometimes it making memory error for large image. What is the best Procedure that I can follow ? Sample image that I want to do ...

[image]

Comment: @ TKumar: Did u get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check a sample code for onclicklistener for images......!!!!!

Java Class:-

```
public OnClickListener onclickimage = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.imageView1:
        rlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView2:
        rlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_evening);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView3:
        rlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_morning);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView4:
        rlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_night);
        break;

    }

}
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

And Layout Code :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

May this Answer can help you.....!!!!!!

You can do the same for ur loop images...!!!!!

Or u Can use theme for the following..!!!!

Sry if i not complete ur any another requirement..!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer . This process can change background of rlayout.xml . but I want to change whole application background . That means all xml of my application , more than 80 xml I used.

Comment: Sry but to change whole background in 80 xml  U can only do it by code nothing else...!!!!!